# Apps Script's spreadsheets "copyTo()" writes the range two times?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Henlo!
I've been stuck on a weird bug in google apps scripts (relative to sheets) and I didn't find any response on internet anywhere.

I have a sheet with filters (~370 lines) and I'm trying to copy its values to another sheet. But when I do that, for some reason, the 370 lines get copied 2 times, and I have absolutely no idea why. Result sheet is 370 lines + one blank line + 370 lines again.

Here's the code I'm using :

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
  var init_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("default");
  var final_sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("final");


  var soure_range = init_sheet.getRange("A1:K");
  var target_range = final_sheet.getRange("N1:X");
  soure_range.copyTo(target_range);
```

if anyone knows why the range gets copied 2 times, I'd be glad to get unstuck :x

EDIT :

As discussed in the comments, this bug seems to appear only when I use a sheets converted from xlsx (the function above works correctly with any other normal sheet).
Here's the convertion function I use :

```
function convert(xlsxID, name, parentFolder) { 
  var xlsxBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(xlsxID).getBlob();
  var file = {
    title: ,
    //Which Drive Folder do you want the file to be placed in
    parents: [{'id':parentFolder}],
    key: 'XXXX',
    value: 'XXXX',
    visibility: 'PRIVATE'
  };

  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, xlsxBlob, {
    convert: true
  });

  return file.getId();
}
```

Comment: There must be something else going on that you're not including. Running your code on a basic spreadsheet with basic data does not show duplicate data.

Comment: is your basic spreadsheet filtered? My source spreadsheet has a filter on, I think the bug comes from here.

Comment: Yes. Still no issue. Only thing I did different was call active spreadsheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7wKtX8-fqAc95sESPIWGNk3saYVYj_6-XqnhUJWVE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: hmmm, it's weird. I tried with a test sheet and it worked fine for me too. I'll try to add a delay between my filter function and the copy one, but I doubt it's this. Maybe the error is from the spreadsheet being originally converted from xlsx? Even though that'd be weird too

Comment: None of those should make a difference. As I said, I think there's something else in your code/sheet that's causing your issue.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the bug here  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/folders/11Iz27g46l-W_C3rpgIWLhybqJxDfqSCa
it even copied it 3 times...
I'll edit the question to add the function I use to convert from xlsx to sheets.

Comment: Oh it's truly an excel file? That's probably your issue. Resave as a google sheet and try.

Comment: I tried to convert the .xlsx file you shared and run the `convert` and `copy` function that you posted and i didn't encountered the issue with duplicate copy. 1135 row data were copied to the `final`sheet. Regarding your shared sample sheet, when I run your `myFunction` it copied the same number of filtered row data to the `final` sheet but as formula so the display value is different. If this is not what you intended, please provide a sample sheet with the expected value

Comment: I really don't understand why it would work with you and not with me. What I do is 1) upload xlsx to drive, 2) convert xlsx to sheets with `convert`, 3) filter the first column to get only the value `lob` (285lines/1135), 4) run the copyTo code that gives me the result you can see yourself in the 2nd "final" sheet: it copied the 285 lines 3 times. ----- I think the function tries to fill the amount of unfiltered rows with the filtered rows until there's not enough room left, but I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: @PGSystemTester that's what the convert version is for. Are you talking about something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue. Initially I did not filter the data from the converted xlsx file.

When copying range using [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination). Use the top-left cell position for your `destination` range.

### Sample Code:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
  var init_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Feuil1");
  var final_sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet("final");


  var soure_range = init_sheet.getRange("A1:K");
  var target_range = final_sheet.getRange("N1"); //Top-left cell position
  soure_range.copyTo(target_range);
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you still encountered some issues so i could update accordingly

Comment: This effectively worked! I still have no idea what causes the duplication to begin with, but thanks for the help

Comment: Based on my understanding, the reason why duplicate copies were done is because you provided a destination range by selecting the whole columns and rows from N to X `var target_range = final_sheet.getRange("N1:X");`

Answer (score 0):

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
const ish = ss.getSheetByName("default");
const fsh = ss.insertSheet("final");
const srg = ish.getRange(1,1,ish.getLastRow(),11);
const vs = srg.getValues();
const trg = fsh.getRange(1,14,vs.length,vs[0].length);
srg.copyTo(trg);
```

Comment: fsh.getLastRow() fails because "the number of rows in the range must be at least 1"